# PHP Yii controller render shows JSON instead of actual page

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, controller, html-rendering

I have a controller with 2 actions - **home** and **run**.
**home** shows a form rendered with a component.
The form submit goes to action **run** which sends a message outside(this part works OK).
I want to render the same page as in **home** again in action **run**.
But the same rendering code that works in **home** - in **run** shows a JSON in the browser.

This is the **run** function of both actions:

```
        public function run()
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $this->controller->layout = "templates.layouts.blank";

    ...Some useful business logic things

    $this->controller->render("templates.rulesrun.home", array(
        "params" => array()
    ));
}
```

The result in the browser looks like this:

{"page":"*HTML of my page*","title":"*Title of my page*"}

PHP version 7.2
Yii version 1.1

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't know anything about Yii, but I can tell you that if you want to send HTML you should not be setting a **Content-type** value of **application/json**. Possibly something in the framework is responding to that?

Comment: This was the first thing I thought about but another action of this controller renders the page with exactly the same code. Also I tried to remove the Content-type line with no effect.